# xCode 4.5 sqlite3_open EXC_BAD_ACCESS in objc_storeStrong

Tags: objective-c, xcode

This code snippet is from a iPad app the is currently in the app store and is written using ARC. The code has developed using xCode 4.4.1 (4F1003) and runs properly in the IOS Simulator 5.1 (272.21). I recently installed xCode 4.5 and IOS Simulator 6.0 and I now get EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x200) when the sqlite3_open returns to my objective C code.

```
sqlite3 *tempDatabase;

const char *sqlStatement = [s_DBEngineDBName UTF8String];
commandReturn = sqlite3_open(sqlStatement, &tempDatabase);  // open main db
if(commandReturn == SQLITE_OK) {
    // ...
}
```

I have previously used the following command to open the database but it also fails in the new environment.

```
commandReturn = sqlite3_open([s_DBEngineDBName cStringUsingEncoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy], &tempDatabase);  // open main db
```

As I stated above stepping thru the SQLite code it all works as expected until the final return statement executes. I am confused as to why objc_storeStrong is even involved.

Comment: What's the value of `sqlStatement`?  What's the full call stack?  What are the arguments to `objc_storeString`?

Comment: Turn on zombies and see if it catches anything.

Answer (score 1):

I tracked the issue down to a forward declaration in an include file:
@class sqlite3; 
which is obviously wrong as sqlite3 is a struct. This was causing the ARC to try and reference count it which is what was raising the exception.

Removing the line caused compile errors which were easily resolved by prefixing the use of sqlite3 with the key word "struct".

Thanks for your suggestions as they got me to dig deeper and realize that the compiler was considering sqlite3 to be a class when in reality it is not.

Comment: What's the class name?